# Spark MLlib: building classifiers for each data group

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have labeled vectors (LabeledPoint-s) taged by some group number. For every group I need to create  *a separate* Logistic Regression classifier:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

object Scratch {

  val train = Seq(
    (1, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 1.0), (2, 3.0))))),
    (1, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((1, 1.5), (2, 4.0))))),
    (1, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 2.0), (1, 1.0), (2, 3.5))))),
    (8, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 3.0), (2, 7.0))))),
    (8, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 1.0), (1, 3.0))))),
    (8, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 1.5), (2, 4.0)))))
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty.server").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    // set up environment
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[5]")
      .setAppName("Scratch")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val trainRDD = sc.parallelize(train)
    val modelByGroup = trainRDD.groupByKey().map({case (group, iter) => 
                           (group, new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().run(iter))})
  }

}
```

`LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().run(iter)` does not compile because `run` works with `RDD` and not with iterator that `groupBy` returns.
Please advise how to build as many classifiers as there are groups (tags) in the input data.

**Update** - demonstrates that nested RDD iteration does not work:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

object Scratch {

  val train = Seq(
    (1, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 1.0), (2, 3.0))))),
    (1, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((1, 1.5), (2, 4.0))))),
    (1, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 2.0), (1, 1.0), (2, 3.5))))),
    (8, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 3.0), (2, 7.0))))),
    (8, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 1.0), (1, 3.0))))),
    (8, LabeledPoint(0, Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 1.5), (2, 4.0)))))
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty.server").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    // set up environment
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[5]")
      .setAppName("Scratch")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val trainRDD = sc.parallelize(train)
    val keys : RDD[Int] = trainRDD.map({case (key,_) => key}).distinct
    for (key <- keys) {
    // key is Int here!
      // Get train data for the current group (key):
      val groupTrain = trainRDD.filter({case (x, _) => x == key }).cache()

      /**
       * Which results in org.apache.spark.SparkException:
       * RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver,
       * not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid
       * because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation.
       * For more information, see SPARK-5063. at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.sc(RDD.scala:87)
       */
    }
  }
}
```

Looks like there is no way to use transformations inside other transformations, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using classifier on each group you don't need mllib. Mllib is designed to use with distributed sets (your sets are not you have butch of local sets on each worker). You can just use some local machine learning library like [weka](https://weka) on each group in map function.

**EDIT:**

```scala
val keys = wholeRDD.map(_._1).distinct.collect

var models = List()
for (key <- keys) {
  val valuesForKey = wholeRDD.filter(_._1 == key)
  // train model
  ...
  models = model::models
}
```

Comment: In each group I have huge data sets to train classifier for the group That's why I can't use Weka. Any other ideas at all?.

Comment: @zork If there is not too many groups you can create one rdd for each group. Just `oneKeyRDD = wholeTrainSetRDD.filter(_._1 == key)`.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too. Unfortunately I have 30 groups!

Comment: @zork Still i think this is the only way. The problem is that by grouping ur making ur data for given key one local set so there is no way to work with it in distributed way (even if the sets are not to big to fit on the one machine). And i guess you can loop throu 30 keys.

Comment: The only way I know to loop distributed keys is Spark `map`. So keys must be an RDD themselves. Yet there is no way to iterate (filter) one RDD inside another RDD! Dead end!

Comment: @zork I added basic example how you can loop over keys in the driver.

Comment: Does not work. Please see my updated question that RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver,
**not inside of other transformations**

Comment: @zork you need to collect keys. You want to iterate over list of keys not over rdd of keys. This way there will be no nesting at all.