# How to operate on RDD by partition?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I would like to repartition data from `RDD[LabeledPoint]` to `K` partitions, and use the `K` partition to train `K` `ml` models respectively in parallel.

The closest operation I know, can produce this, is `.mapPartitionsWithIndex` but it returns `Iterator[LabeledPoint]`, while the model takes `RDD[LabeledPoint]` as input.I think I can convert `Iterator[LabeledPoint]` to `RDD[LabeledPoint]` but it seems redundant to convert from RDD to Iterator and back again.

Below is what I have so far.

```
val K = model.size // models:Array[(idx, Model)]
data.repartition(K) //RDD[LabeledPoint]
data.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
    case (i, dat) => {
        val datByPartition = dat // dat:Iterator[LabeledPoint]
        models(i).train(datByPartition) // however input of "train" needs to be RDD[LabeledPoint]
    ...
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Spark MLlib: building classifiers for each data group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459805/spark-mllib-building-classifiers-for-each-data-group)  is similar to the problem I am having, apparently there was no good solution by then. But it was 3 years ago, I am wondering if it is solvable now .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark MLlib: building classifiers for each data group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459805/spark-mllib-building-classifiers-for-each-data-group)

Comment: Please paste your code as text, indented by 4 positions. This makes it searchable, thus increases the vallue of your contribution to our knowledge base. Also, people that wat to help you will be able to cut nd paste your code to debug it.